# Лексический анализатор на регексах,сделать чтобы пропускал пробелы

Tags: python, структуры

Есть лексический анализатор на регексах со структурой Token

```
#--------------------------------------------------
#Lexer Start
#--------------------------------------------------

class Token(object):
    def __init__(self,type,value):
        self.type=type
        self.value=value
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Token({type},{value})'.format(
      type=self.type,
         value=repr(self.value)
  )
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__
#------------------------------------------------------  
token_exprs=[(r'[ \n]+','None'),
             (r'#[^\n]*','None'),
             (r'\:=','RESERVED'),
             (r'\(','LPAREN'),
                 (r'\)','RPAREN'),
                 (r';','RESERVED'),
                 (r'\+','PLUS'),
                 (r'\.','DOT'),
                 (r'SUM','FUNC'),
                 (r',','DELIMARGS'),
                 (r'-','MINUS'),
                 (r'\*','OP'),
                 (r'\^','OP'),
                 (r'/','OP'),
                 (r'<=','RESERVED'),
                 (r'<','RESERVED'),
                 (r'>=','RESERVED'),
                 (r'>','RESERVED'),
                 (r'!=','RESERVED'),
                 (r'=','RESERVED'),
                 (r'and','RESERVED'),

                 (r'or','RESERVED'),
                 (r'not','RESERVED'),
                 (r'if','RESERVED'),
                 (r'then','RESERVED'),
                 (r'else','RESERVED'),

                 (r'while','RESERVED'),
                 (r'do','RESERVED'),
                 (r'end','RESERVED'),
                 (r'\d+(\.\d*)?','NUM'),
                 (r'[a-z]+','ID'),]
#--------------------------------------------------
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import re
import sys
class Lexer(object):
    def __init__(self,characters,token_exprs):
        self.pos=0
        self.token_exprs=token_exprs
        self.characters=characters
    def get_next_token(self):
        while self.pos<len(self.characters) :#pri pos=0
            match=None
            for token_expr in self.token_exprs:#token_expr=('do', 'RESERVED') #token_exprs=[(r'do','RESERVED')]
                patern,tag=token_expr#patern='do' tag='RESERVED'
                regex=re.compile(patern)#regex=re.compile('do')
                match=regex.match(self.characters,self.pos)#match=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='do'>
                if match:# klass True
                    text=match.group(0)#text='do'
                    if text is not None and text==' ':
                        self.pos+=1
                    if tag:#klass True
                     self.pos=match.end()                       
                     break
            if not match:#not None==not False->True->klass True
                sys.stderr.write('Illegal character:%s\n'% self.characters[self.pos])
                sys.exit(1)
            #else:
            #    self.pos=match.end()  
            return Token(tag,text)    
#--------------------------------------------------
#Lexer End
#--------------------------------------------------
lexer=Lexer('1 11',token_exprs)
print(lexer.get_next_token())
print(lexer.get_next_token())
print(lexer.get_next_token())
print(lexer.get_next_token())
```

Выдает:

```
Token(NUM,'1')
Token(None,' ')
Token(NUM,'11')
None
```

Надо исключить Token(None,' ').
Пытался зделать кодом выше-

```
if text is not None and text==' ':
                        self.pos+=1
```

Что то не получается?Что нужно сделать